# using jquery to determine height:auto and applying it to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have height auto set on this div:

```
div#new-menu-lower ul li ul li ul
```

and i need some jquery to apply the same height to the following div:

```
div#new-menu-lower ul li ul
```

Is this even possible? If you could demo an example that would be fantastic.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('div#new-menu-lower ul li ul').height($('div#new-menu-lower ul li ul li ul').height())
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/antyrat/XJVmR/)

Comment: its applying height zero for me... strange.

Comment: i dont think jquery is clever enough to know what the value of height auto is?!